# How to merge multiple API calls into one call in REST API

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express, http

For instance, if I have an API call `http://localhost:3006/send-message?email=abc@mysite.com&password=xxxxxx&count=4&location=US` and another API call `http://localhost:3006/cancel-request?email=abc@mysite.com&password=xxxxxx&count=2&usernames=abc,xyz`.
So, can I merge these two calls into one by doing something like `http://localhost:3006/send-message?email=abc@mysite.com&password=xxxxxx&count=4&location=US/cancel-request?count=2&usernames=abc,xyz`. If Yes then how I can handle this in Node.js with express.

Comment: The question I would want to ask is: why. Why not do 2 calls?

Comment: @Evert - A couple possible reasons.  1) Reducing the number of separate API calls can improve server or client performance.  2) These two operations may be related and error handling when one has an error can be better managed when one piece of server-side code controls both operations.

Comment: @jfriend00, I get that reasons exists why someone might want to, but I'm explicitly asking OP to better answer their question.

Comment: And if it's indeed your reason #1, I would recommend first making sure it's really needed. Reducing 2 calls to 1 is likely going to not make a difference and you add a lot of complexity. I'd likely also not recommend building a general 'bulk operations' API but instead try and design goal-focused APIs

Comment: @Evert - Well, as it turns out these operations shouldn't be GET operations anyway (at least in a typical REST design) so some redesign is needed regardless.  If the OP ever responds, perhaps they will provide their motivation.

Comment: @Evert First of all it's not just 2 calls actually it's 8 different calls in a row. And, it does some automation tasks. If we call them separately the session has to be initiated each time which hits the captcha. Hence, by merging these calls I can perform all these operations in one session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest making these operations a POST instead of a GET.  Then, you can have one URL for a multi-operation and you can have a JSON payload in the body that contains an array of operations and their parameters:

```
http://localhost:3006/multi-operation
```

With a JSON payload that parses to this:

```
[
   {
       operation: "send-message",
       email: "abc@mysite.com",
       password: "xxxxx",
       count: 4,
       location: "US"
   },
   {
       operation: "cancel-request",
       email: "abc@mysite.com",
       password: "xxxxx",
       count: 2,
       usernames: ["abc","xyz"]
   }
]
```

This would also only be sending sensitive information such as passwords in the body of the request which is generally considered safer than putting them in the URL (where they might get logged by various infrastructure).

Note: In a REST API design, a GET request is not supposed to have "side-effects".  It's supposed to retrieve some resource.  Calling it 0 times, 1 time or 10 times should have the same effect on the server/world.  So, independent of the desire to specify multiple operations in one API call, neither of these operations should have been a GET operation anyway because they both have side effects (they cause some change to occur).  So, these should likely be POST operations.  There are lots of good articles on when to use GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, etc... in a REST API.  If you're confused by this, you can start with these articles or find many others with a search:

https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/

https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html